# Extracting startAngle and endAngle from d attribute of a path - d3

Tags: d3.js

In d3, we find the `d` attribute of a path of a pie chart by feeding pie datum to it, which contains the `startAngle` and `endAngle`. I would like to do some transitions in a JS framework, which requires me knowing the current `startAngle` and `endAngle`, but all I have is a `path` element, and the `d` attribute. Is there an implemented way to find the `startAngle` and `endAngle` from the `d` attribute?

Comment: You'll find out that reverse engineering that is very complicated: https://github.com/d3/d3-shape/blob/289b6ca78ba2fdde523737651866405ec6035587/src/arc.js#L87. It would be better finding another approach.

Comment: Are the paths straight? https://stackoverflow.com/questions/42159032/how-to-find-angle-between-two-straight-lines-paths-on-a-svg-in-javascript/42159152